# Unexpected application pool recycling, why?

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool, recycle

I know that there are several posts about this, but I have a different scenario.

In my case, I disabled all the options that are in the IIS to recycle the application pool

- in minutes,
- in requests,
- at certain time,
- by memory, virtual and used.

There are no changes to the following files that could cause the app pool to recycle:

- Web.config,
- Machine.config,
- Global.asax,
- Bin directory, and
- App_Code

This happens when a Windows Forms application calls a lot of times to a web service hosted on my server - the application pool is recycled, and my Windows Forms application crashes because the web service is not available.

Any ideas of what other thing causes an application pool to recycle?

Comment: Check the event viewer for application pool shut down reasons.

Comment: Does your application pool have any CPU actions to shutdown the process if it's using more than x amount of CPU. There are one or two actions and one of them is to shutdown the app pool which in turn will restart

Comment: Is it recycling or stopping? I believe IIS will shut down the pool if it encounters a certain number of exceptions in a certain time period.